# Parent selector: is it possible to target a div which is inside multiple div?

Tags: css-selectors, parent-child, selector, children

I would like if it's possible to select a div that is the child of two previous div. Based on my code the targeted div is "Middle" but it is inside :
 class="start-page epages no-sidebars"
AND
 class="Layout1 GeneralLayout Div"

I tried ".start-page .Middle " but it doesn't work

```html
<body class="start-page epages no-sidebars" itemtype="http://schema.org/CollectionPage">
    <div class="Layout1 GeneralLayout Div">
  <div class="Header HorizontalNavBar HeaderSticky">
  </div>
  <div class="NavBarTop HorizontalNavBar" style="background-position-y: 90px;">
  </div>
  <div class="Middle">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If that doesn't work then the HTML you provided is not correct. Your use of the term "parent selector" suggests the problem is more complicated than it would seem.

Comment: I don't understand ... my title is not correct? and the code I provided is the one I used also...

Comment: Isn't a parent selector. You want target a child not a parent. Anyway `.start-page .Middle` is correct, probably other css definition have more specificity on this div overriding yours.